# Error handling in ensureuser() method

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, error-handling

I have an issue where I am trying to handle the error but could not get it done.
here is the code:

```
$UserSPU = "domain\user"
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$user = $web.EnsureUser($UserSPR)
```

The above code works well if I have a valid user, But it throws the error when a user is not valid. But what I am trying to get is If a user is not valid then throws my custom errors. This is what i am trying to do but it is not working as expected and throws the error before wrtie-host and exit.

```
If(!($web.EnsureUser($UserSPR)))
 {
Write-Host  $UserSPR " account is not valid"
}
```

Please guide me or fix the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0 
$UserSPU = "domain\user"
$site = Get-SPSite https://sharepoint.example.com
$web = $site.OpenWeb()

try
{
    $user = $web.EnsureUser($UserSPR)
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host 'User not found.'
}
```

Comment: And if I want exit from here then should I type return;?

Comment: That will return from a function. `break` is the other keyword (to exit a loop) or `continue` (to exit the current iteration of the loop but continue looping).

Comment: I want exit from program

Comment: `exit` will exit the script as well as the PowerShell session.